# Use a parameter System.Type T in List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization, generic-list

Suppose I have a function:

```
public static IList GetAllItems(System.Type T) 
{ 

    XmlSerializer deSerializer = new XmlSerializer(T); 

    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(GetPathBasedOnType(T)); 
    IList items = (IList) deSerializer.Deserialize(tr); 
    tr.Close(); 

    return items; 
}
```

In order to retrieve a list of Articles, I would like to call `GetAllItems(typeof(Article))` instead of `GetAllItems(typeof(List<Article>))` but still return a list.

**Question**:  how can I, **without changing the function declaration/prototype**, avoid requiring unnecessary `List<>` portion when calling this function?

That is, I am looking for something like this:

```
public static IList GetAllItems(System.Type T) 
{ 
    /* DOES NOT WORK:  Note new List<T> that I want to have */     
    XmlSerializer deSerializer = new XmlSerializer(List<T>); 

    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(GetPathBasedOnType(T)); 
    IList items = (IList) deSerializer.Deserialize(tr); 
    tr.Close(); 

    return items; 
}
```

Comment: I would go for changing the method signature to use generics, but if thats not an option cdhowie's answer is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a serialized List in the stream, yes?  If so, then just change this, in your second example:

```
XmlSerializer deSerializer = new XmlSerializer(List<T>);
```

To something like this:

```
if (!T.IsGenericType || T.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(List<>))
    T = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { T });

XmlSerializer deSerializer = new XmlSerializer(T);
```

This will examine the type passed in; if it is a `List<T>` then it will be used unmodified.  Otherwise, the appropriate `List<T>` type will be used instead.

In other words, if you pass in `typeof(Foo)` then T will become `List<Foo>`.  But if you pass in `typeof(List<Foo>)` then T will stay `List<Foo>`.

Comment: As a side note, if all you want to do is turn the type T represents into List<T>, without detecting if the T passed in was List<T>, then simply remove the "if" clause and retain the assignment to T.  Then passing in typeof(List<Foo>) would result in T becoming List<List<Foo>>.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling GetAllItems(typeof(Article)), so I assume you know the type statically. If that is indeed the case, how about:

```
public static IList<T> GetAllItems<T>() //Note T is now a type agrument
{
    //the using statement is better practice than manual Close()
    using (var tr = new StreamReader(GetPathBasedOnType(typeof(T)))) 
       return (List<T>)new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>)).Deserialize(tr);
}
```

You'd now call `GetAllItems<Article>()`.

Also, consider using [DataContractSerializer rather than XmlSerializer](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/).